# Polynomial bound for complex exponential function

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Can you help me prove that $\vert \exp(it) - 1 -it \vert \le t^2$, where $t > 0$? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't, perhaps, be an exponent $\;2\;$ in the left side of that inequality?

Comment: @DonAntonio Can you elaborate on it a little bit more?

Comment: Should it be  $\;\vert \exp(it) - 1 -it \vert^{\color{red}2} \le t^2\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio No, what I have been given is the same as the inequality in the post.

Comment: @DonAntonio It should not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can do better, $|\exp(it)-1-it|\leq\frac{t^2}2$. This estimate is stronger than in the OP, and is valid for any real $t$, not just positive. The method below works for estimating the difference between $\exp(it)$ and its Taylor polynomial of any order.

**Proof:**
Applying FTC twice,
$$\exp(it) = 1 + \int_0^ti\exp(is)ds=1+\int_0^ti\left(1+\int_0^si\exp(ir)dr\right)ds\\=1+it-\int_0^tds\int_0^s\exp(ir)dr.$$
Therefore, taking absolute values and using that $|\exp(ir)|=1$ for real $r$:
$$
|\exp(it)-1-it|=\left|\int_0^tds\int_0^s\exp(ir)dr\right|\leq\int_0^tds\int_0^s|\exp(ir)|dr\\
=\int_0^tds\int_0^s1dr=\int_0^tsds=\frac{t^2}2.
$$
**Q.E.D**

Analogous argument shows that $\displaystyle{\left|\exp(it)-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(it)^k}{k!}\right|\leq\frac{t^n}{n!}}$ for any real $t$ and positive integer $n$. The same estimate can be derived without using integrals from the [mean value form for the remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) of the Taylor approximation. And conversely, the mean value form can be derived by this method.

Comment: Oh, beautiful! Thanks so much!